# Check Dependency Convergence for single artifact

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-enforcer-plugin

Consider the following Maven project, having a parent and two modules.

**parent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**module1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**module2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Module 1 has a dependency on `weld-se-core`, which in turn has a dependency on `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api`. Module 2 has itself a dependency on `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api`. Furthermore, module 1 has dependencies to `junit-jupiter` and `mockito-junit-jupiter`, both of which have a dependency on `junit-jupiter-api`, but unfortunately in different versions. *Please consider this as an example. In my real project this is some private third-party dependency with a much larger dependency-tree, which neither can nor want to change*.

As both modules are under my control, I want to make sure that when `weld-se-core` is updated in module 1, `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api` in module 2 is updated accordingly. I tried using the `maven-enforcer-plugin` with the following rules

```
<dependencyConvergence/>
<requireSameVersions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</requireSameVersions>
```

Problem is: `requireSameVersions` does not break the build, when the versions of `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api` don't match while `dependencyConvergence` shows me all errors, not only the one concerning `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api`.

The message when using the `dependencyConvergence` rule is as follows (abbreviated)

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-cdi-same-version) @ module1 ---
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:2.0.2 paths to dependency are:
[...]
+-com.example:module1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:3.1.4.Final
    +-jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:2.0.2
and
+-com.example:module1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example:module2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    +-jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:2.0.1

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2 paths to dependency are:
[...]
+-com.example:module1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2
and
+-com.example:module1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.3.3
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message.
```

The first Warning is wanted, the second one is unwanted.

**Question**: Is there any way to ensure dependency convergence **only for a specific set of dependencies**?

Comment: Can you add the exception log ?

Comment: @AnishB. The log is added